# Appending form with hash function in Jquery

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm working on a password reset form.

My jQuery that was checking if both passwords were the same and the jQuery that hashes the password were clashing, so I tried to combine them, but the hash script is no longer appending a hidden field with the hash to the form.

How can I target the form using the `formhash` method I'm about to include?

Here's my script:

Form `submit`:

```
$('#form').submit(function (e) {
    if ($.trim($("#pwd").val()) != $.trim($("#confirmpwd").val())) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('Passwords do not match!');
        return false;
    } else {
        formhash(this.form, this.form.pwd);
    }
});
```

`formhash` method:

```
function formhash(form, password) {
    var p = document.createElement("input");

    // Add the new element to our form. 
    form.appendChild(p);
    p.name = "p";
    p.type = "hidden";
    p.value = hex_sha512(password.value);

    // Make sure the plaintext password doesn't get sent. 
    password.value = "";

    form.submit();
}
```

and here's the html form for reference:

```
<form method="post" action="query_resetpass.php" id="form">
    <h3>Password Reset Form:</h3>
    <h4>Registered Email: <?php echo $email ?></h4>

    <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="pwd" class="form-control" id="pwd">

    <label for="confirmpwd">Confirm Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="confirmpwd" class="form-control" id="confirmpwd">

    <input type="hidden" name="unique" value="<?php echo $unique ?>">
    <button onclick="" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

How can I nest the `formhash` script in order to make the two scripts play nice?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code. The change is in the elements that you pass to your formhash method.

```
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
    if ($.trim($("#pwd").val()) != $.trim($("#confirmpwd").val())) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('Passwords do not match!');
        return false;
    } else {
        formhash($("#form")[0], $("#pwd")[0]);
    }
});
```

Comment: Damn that was quick and worked! I've never seen that particular syntax before. I am assuming the [0] means something along the lines of first <form> element and first input field?

Comment: @Habitat It means you dereference the jQuery object to get the DOM element :) If the selector selects more than one DOM element, then this dereferences the first one.